# How to Show "\" in the Text View

Tags: android, escaping, typeface

I'm using `TypeFace` to show a Tamil font in the app. the letters goes as this `"fe;j r\;b ftrk;"`

I saved it in the Strings file and trying to retrieve it on the UI. But the `"\"` escapes the next character and I'm missing a character :( as a matter of fact \ represents a letter and I want \ to be shown. How to do this.

Thanks for your time in advance.

My code is as follows

```
package com.mayuonline.kanthan;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Bamini.ttf");
        TextView TextViewWelcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWelcome);
        TextViewWelcome.setTypeface(tf);
        TextViewWelcome.setText(R.string.WelcomeTitle);
       }
}
```

Comment: Your question title says you want to show `"/"` and your question description says you want to show `"\"`. Edit them to match eachother.

Comment: just use escape characters.. try to search these in google. in your case use '//', first will escape the second and allow it to print

Comment: Thanks @harry @ Stuti. It worked :) and I corrected the silly mistake in the title.

Comment: @Stuti - That works for `'\\'`, but `'//'` is illegal (two characters within single quotes) and `"//"` will give a _two character_ string `//`.

Comment: you can print / as it is, the problem comes with \..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` by using it twice: `"fe;j r\\;b ftrk;"`. That will insert a single `\` into the string.